# Using If Else with Foreach in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Hi guys I use codeigniter to perform, conditioning on the View script but to no avail.
Can I help correct correct code writing in the code below?

My logic is:
If the total "amount" in the "InvoiceDash" function is equal to 0,
Then show the foreach function of the "resultAcumulativeSales" function,
If it does not show the foreach function of the "resultAll" function

```
<?php foreach ($hasilInvoiceDash as $data) :
                                                $x = $data->amount; 
                                                endforeach;

                                                if ($x = 0) { foreach ($hasilAcumulativeSales as $data) : $a = $data->sales;
                                                                    $b = 30 ;
                                                                    $c = $b*$a/100  ; 
                                                                    $d =  $a - $c ; ?>

                                                                    <?php if ($a < "1") { ?>
                                                                        <h2 class="m-b-0"> <?php echo "0"; ?> </h2>
                                                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                                                        <h2 class="m-b-0"> <?php echo $d ; ?> </h2>
                                                                    <?php } endforeach;  ?>


                                        <?php } else{ foreach ($hasilSemua as $data) : ?>

                                            <h2 class="m-b-0">Rp. <?php  
                                                 $a = $data->total_sales;
                                                 $b = 30 ;
                                                 $c = $b*$a/100  ; 
                                                 $d =  $a - $c ;
                                                 echo $d ; ?> </h2>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?> 
                                            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrote wrong syntax for if condition.

use

```
if ($x == 0) {
```

instead of

```
if ($x = 0) {
```

Comment: But whether the other code writing has been correct because I always get an error on the use of Foreach ?

Comment: $hasilInvoiceDash must be array. if not then please show me your controller code.

Comment: Actually I use the parsing function in Model file and here's my model function [https://pastebin.com/wsqyPWNE](https://pastebin.com/wsqyPWNE)

Comment: Please declare $hasilInvoice = array(); before if condition. This will return empty array in case of not record found for query.

Comment: can you show how ? may be in pastebin.com again , so I know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here you made a small mistake, if you use `if ($x = 0)` it means for every iteration you are assigning value of `$x= 0`.

```
1. = operator is used to assign the value
2. == Returns true if condition matched without type matching
3. === Returns true if condition and type matched
```

If you want to compare the value of `$x` the please find below mentioned solutions.

Without type matching

```
if($x == 0)
```

With type matching

```
if ($x === 0)
```

Let me know if you have any other error.